# Cancel partially an observable

Tags: rxjs, observable

Here is my scenario with the constraints:

I'm making a front end in React using react-observable and there are buttons that call the API and fetch result. **The order in which you press the buttons matters for the final result so the calls must not be interrupted.**

Every call will give back a huge JSON response which override every previous result. **The loading of the JSON should only happen for the very last result of the API.**

---

As an example:

There are 3 buttons: A, B and C.

- If I click on A, then B, then C:

  The program must call the API for the A action, wait for the response to be available without parsing the JSON, then call the B action and do the same (wait but do not parse) then at the very end the program must call the C action wait and process its result.
- If I click on B, then C, then A:

  The result will not be the same than the previous use case but process is similar: call, wait, call, wait, call, wait, read result
- I can click any time and as much buttons I want.

---

What I did:

To me it seems I need to use concat to run every calls sequentially but also takeUntil to cancel any action any time.

```
const epic1 = action$
    .typeOf(TYPE_X)
    .mapTo({ type: START_ACTION })

const epic2 = action$
    .typeOf(TYPE_X)
    .concatMap(action =>
        postToAPI(action)
            .map((response) => Observable.from(response.json()))
            .map((data) => generate_action_to_process_data(data))
            .takeUntil(
                action$.ofType(START_ACTION)))
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as expected. The whole observer is canceled and it doesn't wait for the reponse to come back at all. Even worst: the calls are somehow executed in parallel because the promise itself continues running.

Comment: so if I just click "A" and that query finishes before I click anything else then we process just the "A" result?

Comment: exactly. this things really matter when the queries take time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this can do it.

Essentially, when the first action occurs, we start the API call and keep the Promise for it (I am using `toPromise` to ensure the query starts since I don't know what your `postToAPI` really does).

If another action occurs before that promise resolves, then I use `then` to chain the new API call to the end of the previous, and we stop listening to the first promise and instead listen to the chained promise.

This repeats as long as the user clicks buttons.  If the chained promise ever completes, then its response will get emitted.  So whenever we see a response emitted, we "reset" the chain and then process the final response.

```
const actions = action$.typeOf(TYPE_X);
const epic = Observable.defer(() => {
  let current;

  return actions
    .switchMap(action => {
      if (current) {
        // run the new query after the current one finishes
        // ignore the actual response of the current query
        current = current.then(() => postToAPI(action).toPromise());
      }
      else {
        // no query running.  start this query now
        current = postToAPI(action).toPromise();
      }
    })
    // if the query chain finishes, then clear the chain
    .do(() => current = null)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .map(data => generate_action_to_process_data(data));
});

epic.subscribe(processDataActions => ...);
```

We wrap the whole construct in `defer` just so that we can construct a new closure variable `current` for each subscription to this epic observable so different observers do not interfere with each other.  Probably unnecessary in this context, but I did it for completeness sake.

Comment: thx! +1 for the variable `current` in the closure. I thought also about storing the promise but in a global variable and my conclusion was: it's quite ugly and I believe a better solution using the stream of actions should exist.Now I'm starting to think that this particular case with promises doesn't exist because the point with observables is to stop listening to an observable and ignore the underlying promise. It's a shame though, I added react-observables to the project to deal with all the asynchronous issues I need to address

Comment: Is it necessary to clear the chain at the end? I just posted my current solution based on yours. I get rid of the second `if() {}` by initializing `current` to a resolved promise and I also don't clear the variable. Do you know if it is unadvised to keep a promise chaining forever like that?

Comment: yeah I guess you don't have to.  The old promises should get GC'd.

Comment: I forgot to validate the answer. Better late than never I guess :) I wonder why the question has been downvoted though...

Comment: Who really understands these things. I upvoted to get you back to 0 lol

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @brandon I made this solution:

```
const epicX = (action$, { getState }) => {
    let promise: Promise<any> = Promise.resolve()
    let loadResult: (response: Response) => Observable<Action>

    return action$
        .ofType(TYPE_X)
        .switchMap(action => {
            const { query, load } = process_call_to_api_x(action, getState)
            if (query === undefined) return Observable.empty()
            loadResult = load
            promise = promise.then(() => query.toPromise())
            return Observable.from(promise)
        })
        .flatMap(response => loadResult(response))
}
```

Which I think could be simplified to...

```
const epicX = (action$, { getState }) => {
    let promise: Promise<any> = Promise.resolve()

    return action$
        .ofType(TYPE_X)
        .switchMap(action => {
            const query: Observable<Response> = postToAPI(action)
            promise = promise.then(() => query.toPromise())
            return Observable.from(promise)
        })
        .flatMap(response => Observable.from(response.json()))
        .flatMap(data => generate_action_to_process_data(data))
}
```